# One .mjs file that works on the browser and NodeJS using native JS Modules

Tags: javascript

Apologies if this question was answered, I tried searching but couldn't find what I'm looking for.

I want to build one `.mjs` file that has a library class code that I can use on both browser and Node.js. I don't want to use browsify or any 3rd party library. I want to use native JS Modules (.mjs). I'm willing to use Node 13.x so I completely replace my `require` statements with `import` and running experimental mode.

Here is an example, I want to use "node-fetch" for NodeJS and the native `fetch` API for the browser. So I called my variable "fetch". But I want to do an if statement so that if I'm running in the browser I can just use the native `fetch`, but If I'm in Node, I want to load the fetch api from `node-fetch` package.

**fetch.mjs -shared code**

```
//if node then do this.. else fetch will be defined in the browser
import fetch from "node-fetch" 

export class AwesomeClass {

        constructor(url)
        {   

            this.url= url;

        }

        load () {

             return fetch(this.url);
        } 
        getAwesome() {} 

}
```

**index.mjs Node JS Client**

```
import { AwesomeClass } from "./fetch.mjs"
const a = new AwesomeClass();
```

**index.html browser Client**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body> 
    <script type = 'module'>
        import { AwesomeClass } from "./fetch.mjs"

        const a = new AwesomeClass();

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use a dynamic `import` statement to include node-fetch if needed. See https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_code_import_code_expressions

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [@Heretic Monkey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/215552/heretic-monkey) for introducing me to dynamic `import` I was able to write a single .mjs file that works on both browser and node js. Here is the code for those interested.

It actually forced me to only load the fetch when I need it.

**fetch.mjs library**

```
export class AwesomeClass {

        constructor(url)
        {   

            this.url= url;

        }

        load () { 

             return import ("node-fetch").then(nodeFetch => nodeFetch.default(this.url)).catch(e=> fetch(this.url))   

        } 
        getAwesome() {} 

}
```

**index.mjs (node.js client)**

```
import {AwesomeClass} from './fetch.mjs'

const ac = new AwesomeClass("https://api.github.com");

(async () => {
    try{
        const res = await ac.load();
        console.log(await res.json());
    }
    catch(e)
    {console.error(e)}

})()
```

**index.html (browser)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body> 
    <script type = 'module'>
        import {AwesomeClass} from './fetch.mjs'

        const ac = new AwesomeClass("https://api.github.com");


        (async () => {
            try{
                const res = await ac.load();
                console.log(await res.json());
            }
            catch(e)
            {console.error(e)}

        })()
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```